# Optimal way to cut grass on the rectangular area.

Tags: optimization, euclidean-geometry, calculus-of-variations

A field of grass has sizes 25 metres $\times$ 40 metres. A lawnmower can cut 40 cm at width. Lazy gardener wants to cut the field of grass by pushing the mower with minimum distance. How should he cut the grass? I was wondering if he goes along straight lines and then turn the mower such that it manages to cut exactly all the grasses on the boundary. But I was unable to prove that the strategy is optimal.

Comment: Presumably there is some kind of inefficiency turning $90^\circ$, so you want to minimise this.  Is this is half the inefficiency turning $180^\circ$ onto a adjacent parallel path?

Comment: @Henry Each time you turn, whether 90°, 180°, or through some other angle, you miss some grass to the outside of the turn. Mowing the entire field involves some combination of overlap and/or backtracking.

Answer (score 2):

Just a tangential note:
Your particular problem, and many natural variants, are NP-hard for regions
more complicated than rectangles.

> Arkin, Esther M., Michael A. Bender, Erik D. Demaine, Sándor P. Fekete, Joseph SB Mitchell, and Saurabh Sethia. "Optimal covering tours with turn costs." *SIAM Journal on Computing* 35, no. 3 (2005): 531-566.
>   ([arXiv abs](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0309014).)
>
> Arkin, Esther M., Sándor P. Fekete, and Joseph SB Mitchell. "Approximation algorithms for lawn mowing and milling." *Computational Geometry* 17, no. 1-2 (2000): 25-50.
>   ([Journal link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925772100000158#FN001).)

---

[image]

---